# How can i get python to check if every term of a input is in list1, and if not print the term as is?

Tags: python, list, slice

This is my code so far. I'm trying to "decode" the user's input by printing the character `n1` spaces ahead but I'm looking for a way to print characters that aren't letters unaltered

```
n=input("Enter code")
n1=int(n[0])
newcode=n[1:]
list1=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'
   ,'m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B',
   'C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R'
   ,'S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
list2=[]
for x in newcode:
    n=list1.index(x)
    n2=n-n1
    y=list1[n2]
    print(y)

> Sample input: 3wkh 
>sample output: 
>t 
>h 
>e 
>sample input: 3wkh fdu 
>sample output: 
>t 
>h 
>e 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
>File "D:\Computer Science\Comp Sci club problems\data1.py", line 10, in <module>
>     n=list1.index(x) ValueError: ' ' is not in list 
>This is the problem that i am having. Please help!
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Give some sample input/output.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! As you can see, the community is reacting a bit negatively to your question, probably partly because you haven't actually asked a question, nor formatted it correctly (the indentation is off, so it wouldn't even run). There are also some antipatterns (`if ... == False:`). How exactly is your program not behaving as you expected, and what have you tried so far to fix it?

Comment: Also, take a look at [PEP-8 (Style Guide for Python code)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to get into the habit of writing readable code as soon as possible. I'll fix your code for you now...(also re-indenting it, I hope that's OK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a check to see whether the given element is in the list before the line:

```
n=list1.index(x)
```

like this:

```
if x in list1:
    n=list1.index(x)
    n2=n-n1
    y=list1[n2]
    print(y)
else:
    print(x)
```

but to finish the problem, I guess you want the transformed list to be stored in list2, right? In that case you could do this:

```
st = ''
for x in newcode:
    if x in list1:
        n=list1.index(x)
        n2=n-n1
        y=list1[n2]
        st += y
    else:
        st += x
print(st)
```

This is a quick and dirty way to put all your characters in a string called st, and then print out the string at the end.

Comment: thank you for your help, but right now when i input 3wkh fdu I get the output t h e  c a r spread out over a different line for each letter, how can i fix that?

Comment: I'll edit my answer now for having it printed out in one line

Comment: If that does the trick for you, please mark my answer as a solution =)